# Truncate unwanted part from string in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data looks like following:

```
Particulars
IMPS/P2A/924413019791/CRYSTALV/THEGREAT/
MOB/QYW6RJS14956/Ratnakar Bank CreditCard
IMPS/P2A/924517325604/rajdha/HDFCBAN/X539003/
BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802/9635/040919/JABALPU
IMPS/P2A/924809539696/pradee/THEGREA/X783336/
IMPS/P2A/924911569760/HARISHMA/ICICIBAN/NA
IMPS/P2A/924916252301/pradee/THEGREA/X783336/
BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802/462/070919/JABALPU
AXMOB/MBR/38VRWY425344/915010029584916/080919
NEFT/MB/AXMB192527472717/Pradeep sbi
```

I need truncate all characters after second forward `/` (slash)

Disired result:

```
IMPS/P2A
MOB/QYW6RJS14956
IMPS/P2A
BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802
IMPS/P2A
IMPS/P2A
IMPS/P2A
BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802
AXMOB/MBR
NEFT/MB
```

Obviously I have used lstrip and rstrip here but it doesn't work. Please let me know if there is any other way I can solve this problem. Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks in advance and please ignore any mistakes in posting my question as it is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by second `/`, then select first 2 lists by indexing and last use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Particulars'] = df['Particulars'].str.split('/', n=2).str[:2].str.join('/')
print (df)
                     Particulars
0                       IMPS/P2A
1               MOB/QYW6RJS14956
2                       IMPS/P2A
3  BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802
4                       IMPS/P2A
5                       IMPS/P2A
6                       IMPS/P2A
7  BY CASH DEPOSIT-BNA/SWRO12802
8                      AXMOB/MBR
9                        NEFT/MB
```